# Sylius - Extend Product fixtures from CoreBundle

Tags: sylius

I've extended the Product model from CoreBundle (v1.0.0-alpha) and I want to change the behavior of the fixtures based on this new model. Keeping in mind that CoreBundle\Fixture\Factory\ProductExampleFactory is final, I am looking for a way to extend the fixtures so I don't have to rewrite the whole class and the whole "default" suite.

**AppBundle\Entity\Product**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product as BaseProduct;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @author leogout
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="sylius_product")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product extends BaseProduct
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Package", mappedBy="component")
     */
    protected $packages;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $exposed;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Customization", mappedBy="product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customization_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $customizations;

    /**
     * Product constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->packages = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->customizations = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set exposed
     *
     * @param boolean $exposed
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setExposed($exposed)
    {
        $this->exposed = $exposed;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get exposed
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getExposed()
    {
        return $this->exposed;
    }

    /**
     * Add packages
     *
     * @param Package $packages
     * @return Product
     */
    public function addPackage(Package $packages)
    {
        $this->packages[] = $packages;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove packages
     *
     * @param Package $packages
     */
    public function removePackage(Package $packages)
    {
        $this->packages->removeElement($packages);
    }

    /**
     * Get packages
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getPackages()
    {
        return $this->packages;
    }

    /**
     * Add customizations
     *
     * @param Customization $customizations
     * @return Product
     */
    public function addCustomization(Customization $customizations)
    {
        $this->customizations[] = $customizations;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove customizations
     *
     * @param Customization $customizations
     */
    public function removeCustomization(Customization $customizations)
    {
        $this->customizations->removeElement($customizations);
    }

    /**
     * Get customizations
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getCustomizations()
    {
        return $this->customizations;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT :**
After some digging, I saw that I needed to code a whole new fixture with a new `ProductFixture`, a new `ProductExampleFactory` and a new `MyCustomProductFixture` on top of that with their own config files which is not ideal... Do you have a better solution ?